# Shiny Plot Refreshes Twice Each Time User Changes Input

Tags: r, plot, shiny, plotly, dt

In my app, when the user updates the selectInput 'client', my plotly plot refreshes twice. It's due to the data passed to the plotly function below via the reactive filtered_data. I have my app setup so that when a user filters the DT table covered_lives, the plot refreshes so that it only plots rows left after the filter.

EDIT: I added a reproducible example below.

```
filtered_data <- reactive({

    covered_lives_data()[input$covered_lives_rows_current, ]

  })
```

The data above depends on:

1. covered_lives_data(): this depends on the select input input$client.

```
covered_lives_data <- reactive({

 

   

    query <- stringr::str_c("SELECT * FROM COVERED_LIVES

                            WHERE NAME = '", input$client, "' AND

                          (MEDICARE > 0 OR COMMERCIAL > 0 OR MEDICAID > 0 OR MARKETPLACE > 0 OR TOTAL > 0 OR CONTRACT_AMOUNT > 0 ) AND LINE_OF_BUSINESS <> 'AIS Payer Portrait TOTAL'")

    dbGetQuery(db, query)

  })
```

2. input$covered_lives_rows_current: The rows currently viewable in the DT output$covered_lives.

I believe this is why my plot refreshes twice when a user select a new client input. First the covered_lives_data refreshes because input$client changes. Next input$covered_lives_rows_current changes because output$covered_lives changes.

How can I change this so that the plot just refreshes once when the user changes the client input?

Here's the full code for the app.

```
library(shinythemes)

library(shiny)

library(shinyjs)

library(DT)

library(DBI)

library(plotly)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram

ui <- navbarPage(title = "Project Moneyball",

                 theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),

                 useShinyjs(),

                 tabPanel("Covered Lives",

                          sidebarLayout(

                            sidebarPanel(

                              width = 3,

                              conditionalPanel("input.lives_panel == 'Client Details'",

                                               selectInput("client", "Client", choices = sort(unique(DBI::dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM COVERED_LIVES")$NAME))),

                                               h4("Covered Lives Totals"),

                                               tableOutput("totals_row_one"),

                                               tableOutput("totals_row_two"),

                                               tableOutput("totals_row_three"),

                                               uiOutput("client_info")

                              ),

                              conditionalPanel(

                                "input.lives_panel == 'Summary'",

                                summary_html

                              )

                             

                            ),

                            mainPanel(

                              tabsetPanel(id = "lives_panel",

                                          tabPanel("Summary",

                                                   DT::DTOutput("summary")),

                                          tabPanel('Client Details',

                                                   shinycssloaders::withSpinner(

                                                     plotly::plotlyOutput("covered_lives_plot")),

                                                   DT::dataTableOutput("covered_lives")))

                            )

                           

                            

                          ))#,

                 

)

 

 

 

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  covered_lives_data <- reactive({

 

   

    query <- stringr::str_c("SELECT * FROM COVERED_LIVES

                            WHERE NAME = '", input$client, "' AND

                          (MEDICARE > 0 OR COMMERCIAL > 0 OR MEDICAID > 0 OR MARKETPLACE > 0 OR TOTAL > 0 OR CONTRACT_AMOUNT > 0 ) AND LINE_OF_BUSINESS <> 'AIS Payer Portrait TOTAL'")

    dbGetQuery(db, query)

  })

 

  covered_lives_totals <- reactive({

    query <- stringr::str_c("SELECT Medicare, Commercial, Medicaid, Marketplace, Total FROM COVERED_LIVES

                            WHERE NAME = '", input$client, "' AND

                           LINE_OF_BUSINESS = 'AIS Payer Portrait TOTAL'")

    dbGetQuery(db, query)

  })

 

  output$totals_row_one <- renderTable(covered_lives_totals() %>% select(Medicare, Commercial) %>%

                                         mutate(Medicare = prettyNum(Medicare,","),

                                                Commercial = prettyNum(Commercial, ",")))

  output$totals_row_two <- renderTable(covered_lives_totals() %>% select(Medicaid, Marketplace) %>%

                                         mutate(Medicaid = prettyNum(Medicaid,","),

                                                Marketplace = prettyNum(Marketplace, ",")))

  output$totals_row_three <- renderTable({

    covered_lives_totals() %>% select(Total) %>% mutate(Total = prettyNum(Total, ","))

   

    # rownames(data) <- 'Covered Lives'

    # return(data)

  }

  )

 

  output$client_info <- renderUI({

    client_info(covered_lives_data())

  })

 

  

  

 

 

  output$covered_lives <- DT::renderDataTable(

    datatable(

      covered_lives_data() %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) %>% #mutate(across(c("Line_of_Business","Contract_Measurement", "Billing_Event", "Growth_Opportunity"), as.factor)) %>%  rename(LOB = Line_of_Business)

        select(-one_of(c("File", "Row_Number", "Update_Date", "Name"))), #%>% select(-Row_Number)

      options = list(dom = "ft", pageLength = 10000),

      selection = list(mode = 'single', target = "row"),

      filter = "top" # Add a filter for the top of the table

    ) %>% formatStyle(

      c('Growth_Opportunity', 'Billing_Event'),

      backgroundColor = styleEqual(c('NO', 'YES'), c('white', 'green')),

      color = styleEqual(c("NO", "YES"), c("black", "white"))

    ) %>%

      formatRound(c("Medicare", "Commercial", "Medicaid", "Marketplace", "Total", "Contract_Amount"), digits = 0)

  )

 

  

  

  

 

  

  

  # Add a reactive value to store the filtered data based on the rows being displayed in the DT after the filter

  filtered_data <- reactive({

    covered_lives_data()[input$covered_lives_rows_current, ]

  })

 

  # ...

 

  output$covered_lives_plot <- renderPlotly({

    
    req(input$client, input$covered_lives_rows_current)


    # Generate the plot based on the filtered data

    covered_lives_bar_plot(filtered_data())

  })

 

  

  

  output$summary <- DT::renderDT({datatable(client_summary, filter = "top",

                                            selection = list(mode = 'single', target = "row"),

                                            options = list(dom = "ft", pageLength = 10000))})

 

  observeEvent(input$summary_rows_selected, {

    client_selected <- client_summary$Name[input$summary_rows_selected]

   

    updateSelectInput(session, "client", selected = client_selected)

  })
```

Here's a simple example of an app with the same issue that you can run:

```
#

library(dplyr)

library(DT)

library(shiny)

iris_list <- replicate(200, iris, simplify = FALSE)

 

# Merge the iris datasets together

iris <- do.call(rbind, iris_list) %>%

  mutate(Name = as.factor(sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = 30000, replace = TRUE)))

 



ui <- fluidPage(

 

    # Application title

    titlePanel("Example"),

 

 

    sidebarLayout(

        sidebarPanel(

           selectInput("name", "Name", choices = sort(unique(iris$Name)))

        ),

 

        

        mainPanel(

          plotOutput("plot"),

           DT::DTOutput("iris_table")

          

        )

    )

)

 


server <- function(input, output) {

  iris_data <- reactive({

    iris %>% filter(Name == input$name)

  })

 

  output$iris_table <- DT::renderDT(datatable(iris_data(), options = list(dom = "ft", pageLength = 10000),

                                    filter = "top"))

 

  plot_data <- reactive({

    iris_data()[input$iris_table_rows_current,]

  })

 

  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(plot_data()$Sepal.Length, plot_data()$Sepal.Width))

 

   

}

 

# Run the application

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```